# Maximum number of values in an array

Tags: javascript

I have an array to have a maximum of 10 elements. Whenever I add a new element, if it already has 10, it would remove the first and push a new one.

I made this:

```
Array.prototype.pushMax = function(value,max){

     if (this.length >= max){
           this.shift();
     }
     this.push(value);

}
```

Which seems to work fine, however, I'm just wondering if there is a better way to do it (perhaps some native JavaScript function)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no native way to do this so your general logic seems sound.  Here's some improvements, you might consider:

1. Make sure the pushMax function is not enumerable so people who iterate arrays with `for (var index in array)` won't see the pushMax property.
2. Ensure the array stays below max length even if it was previously above max
3. Return the new length of the array, the same as `.push()`:

Here's a working snippet:

```js
Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, "pushMax", {
    configurable: false,
    enumerable: false,
    writable: false,
    value: function(value, max) {
        if (this.length >= max) {
           this.splice(0, this.length - max + 1);
      }
      return this.push(value);
    }
});



var x = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
x.pushMax(11, 10);
x.pushMax(12, 10);
x.pushMax(13, 10);

// wrong way to iterate an array, but just testing enumerability
for (var i in x) {
    document.write(i + ": " +  x[i] + "<br>");
}
```

---

You could also consider making the max length be a non-enumerable property of the array so you don't have to pass it to `.pushMax()` every time.

---

I'd really rather see this in a subclass of an Array rather than modifying the built-in Array object, but alas we can't subclass the Array object yet in most browsers.